# access_token audience is not for this project

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I`m developing a react-native project and it has configured 2 firebase projects for production and testing. I`m getting 'access_token audience is not for this project' error while trying to authenticate from google via firebase

```
 let authProvider = Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    null,
    authToken
  );    
let responseSignInWithCredential = await 
      Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(
        authProvider
      ); //error getting from here!
```

That error is getting only I configured it with testing environment. Also Wonder Its affected previously build version as well (those are worked without any fault last week).

Comment: Did you try with a different access token?

Comment: Yes, This is working for production environment settings without any fault.

Comment: [Youtube video for how to generate SHA1 key and configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678087/access-token-audience-is-not-for-this-project)

Comment: Adding both SHA-1 and SHA-256 checksums in the firebase console fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed debug.keystore located in .android folder and again generated a SHA-1 and added it to firebase project.Its worked

Answer (score 0):

The development config has the SHA-1 for the debug build, and the production config has the SHA-1 for the release build. This error occurs when you use the the debug build with the prod config. make sure your  build's SHA-1 fingerprint  match the one in Firebase project

Comment: thats for android only isn`t it?

Comment: I have solved IOS issue, but android version issue is there, how can I generate different SHA-1 for each build?

Comment: Thanks @sri I have removed debug.keystore located in .android folder and again generated a SHA-1 and added it to firebase project.Its worked.